# Why my 64bit app runs with 32bit DLLs?

Tags: c#

I compiled my C# app in 64 bit, but some DLLs are still in 32bit, namely FSharp.Core.dll. I used:

```
dumpbin /headers FSharp.Core.dll
```

And it's x86 not x64. But the app still runs correctly. Why is this?

Comment: 32-bit apps can run on 64-bit. It's the reverse that isn't true.

Comment: The accepted answer to the question seems to be incorrect - or at least inaccurate. Look at the other answers instead.

Comment: @ChrisF I don't think it's about that. I think it's because `dumpbin` reads the COFF header while the VS C# app puts its actual bitness in the CLR part of the EXE. In other words, OP is probably reading two different pieces of information.

Comment: Dumpbin.exe will *always* show the "machine" field in the header set to x86.  Even though the assembly works just fine a 64-bit process.  Lots of technical details behind this, but the simplest way to reason it out is that a .NET assembly does not contain any executable code.  It contains **data**, it takes the just-in-time compiler to turn that data it into code that can run on a processor.

Comment: @HansPassant Indeed. That's why I think this isn't a duplicate of the other question, since the other isn't about CLR assemblies.